# Resize 1D array that defines a 2d square of tiles

Tags: c#

I have a 1D array defining a grid of tile. Each Each tile has 8*8 elements. Each element can have a value of 0 or 1. I can have different width and height.

I need to be able to resize this array, allowing to add or remove more tiles to the right or add or remove more tiles to the bottom.

Example:

```
1D array with 1x1 tile, 8*8 elements. As you can see each corner has a value of 1
{
1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1
}

I expect to have this result when I expand the array to have 2x2 tiles, 16*16 elements. Has you can see the corners of the first tile remain positioned correctly while the tiles are expanded.
{
1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,   0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,   0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,   0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,   0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,   0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,   0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,   0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,   0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,

0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,   0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,   0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,   0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,   0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,   0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,   0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,   0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,   0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
}
```

I have tried several ways, and while I can successfully scale up and down the array, the element values are not positioned correctly.

My last try:

```
static int[] ResizeSquare(int[] originalSquare, int originalWidth, int originalHeight, int newWidth, int newHeight)
{
    int elementsPerTile = 8 * 8;
    int[] resizedSquare = new int[newWidth * newHeight * elementsPerTile];

    for (int row = 0; row < Math.Min(originalHeight, newHeight); row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < Math.Min(originalWidth, newWidth); col++)
        {
            int originalTileIndex = row * originalWidth + col;
            int newTileIndex = row * newWidth + col;

            for (int i = 0; i < elementsPerTile; i++)
            {
                // Calculate the position within the original and resized squares
                int originalPosition = originalTileIndex * elementsPerTile + i;
                int newPosition = newTileIndex * elementsPerTile + i;

                // Copy the original value to the corresponding position in the resized square
                resizedSquare[newPosition] = originalSquare[originalPosition];
            }
        }
    }

    return resizedSquare;
}
```

This result in, which is wrong.

```
{
1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,   0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,   0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,   0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,   1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,   0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,   0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,   0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,   0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,

0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,   0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,   0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,   0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,   0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,   0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,   0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,   0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,   0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you want/need to jump around the data sets like that?  The first "row" of the resized array contains data from 2 sets.  It makes more sense to have the data sets be contiguous (think single column of tiles), which makes the maths easy, and then display it however you like.  I think you are making the problem harder than it needs to be by interweaving multiple data sets together like that.

Comment: I would recommend looking for a different approach. Unless memory or speed is of upmost importance, I would create a tile class and then just have a 2d array of tiles.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I agree with both assessments, however this part of a program already working and changing the internal structure would mean breaking compatibility, which I am not keen to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
for (int row = 0; row < Math.Min(originalHeight, newHeight); row++)
{
    Array.Copy(originalSquare,  // Array to copy from
               row * originalWidth, // index to copy from
               resizedSquare, // Array to copy tp
               row * newWidth, // index to copy to
               Math.Min(originalWidth, newWidth)); // Number of items to copy
}
```